# Excel Return Array if condition is true

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I am trying to get something of the effect that when I have an if statement: if({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE},{1,2,3}) it will return with {1,3} is there any way to get this effect with an array of conditions and return an array of results?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If this is a formula, maybe show us what the whole formula is?

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula FILTER:

```
=FILTER({1,2,3},TRANSPOSE({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}))
```

Without dynamic Array formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(IF({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE},ROW(1:3)*{1,1})))
```

This is an array formula and depending on ones version, it may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will do what you say you want.

Note that there are a bunch of `TRANSPOSE` functions.  This is because your Booleans are semicolon separated and your `condition_if_true` result is comma separated.

```
 =TRANSPOSE(AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(1/{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE},TRANSPOSE({1,2,3})),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"& SUM(--{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE})))))
```

[image]