# Returning from an array

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

Maybe this has been asked before, but I don't even know what to search.

I have an array in Excel of n items. 
I also have a binary array of n items and for each 1 in that binary array, I want to return the item its position corresponds to in the original array. For example, let's say I have: {A, B, C, D} and {0,0,1,1}. I want to return only C and D since those are the places that have 1s. 
Is there a way to do that in Excel?

Thanks.

Best,

Morris

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827969/excel-formula-to-create-an-array-of-lookup-values-based-on-a-criteria

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456891/excel-return-array-if-condition-is-true/60457558#60457558

Comment: As you can see you got two totally different answers.  May be better if you mocked up the data set and expected output, show how it looks on your sheet and what you wnat it to show on the sheet afterwards. [edit] your question to add these details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=INDEX({"A","B","C","D"},N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF({0,0,1,1},COLUMN($A:$D)*{1;1})))))
```

Depending on ones version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

My version automatically spills arrays so putting it in A1 gives me the full array output spilled down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function xtract(s1 As String, binpatrn As String) As String
    Dim arr1, arr2, i As Long
    arr1 = Split(s1, ",")
    arr2 = Split(binpatrn, ",")

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        If arr2(i) = "1" Then
            xtract = xtract & "," & arr1(i)
        End If
    Next i
    If xtract = "" Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        xtract = Mid(xtract, 2)
    End If
End Function
```

We place the comma-separated list *(without braces)* in **A1** and the binary list *(without braces )* in **B1**. In **C1** enter:

```
=xtract(A1,B1)
```

[image]